# Handling of command line errors in a GUI app

Tags: user-interface, command-line

In a console application the normal behaviour for a usage error is to report it and exit.

What is the 'correct' behaviour for a GUI application?

- should it exit or continue running?
- should it write to stderr or open a message box
- should it write to the application log file if there is one?

**Clarification**: by a usage error I particularly mean something like:

*"--BAD"* when the application has no such option.
File not found is another interesting case however.

---

### Examples

I looked at some existing GUI applications for inspiration:

- Word - accepts positional command line arguments which it treats as names of files to open.
  Unknown options are ignored.
- Chrome - accepts positional command line arguments which it treats as URLs to open.
  Unknown options are ignored.
- Devenv (Visual Studio)

  - reports command line errors to the terminal if launched from the terminal.
  - reports command line errors as a messagebox if launched from a shortcut
  - exits either way
- Emacs - accepts positional command line arguments which it treats as names of files to open.
  Unknown options are ignored.

---

### Context

I was slightly nonplussed by an argument from colleagues that the right thing to do is just to open the application anyway and ignore the errors
(I'm firmly in the "silently ignoring errors is bad" camp).

My feeling is that the 'right' thing to do is as the Visual Studio example above. Report an error and exit. Using a messagebox if there is no stderr channel.

What reason could there be to ignore usage errors?

Some possible arguments:

- The command line is for **expert** users and failure to open the application would confuse them.
  This is possibly condescending. It also doesn't explain Emacs which is firmly in the Posix camp where doing command lines *right* is more important.
- I think the main one is that in general "*Errors do not stop a GUI application*" is drummed
  in the GUI Ux mindset.
  In the case of command line processing the application hasn't really started yet so you could argue it shouldn't apply.

I looked around for GUI design guidelines that might cover this but I have not found any so far.
The two below are interesting for context as they discuss error handling though not specifically the command line.

https://www.sapien.com/blog/2015/01/15/manage-errors-in-a-gui-application/
https://www.userjourneys.com/blog/ux-guidelines-for-error-handling/

### Note

I previously asked [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/149356/handling-of-command-line-errors-in-a-gui-app) on UX but it is a relatively low traffic site and I think their focus is more on GUI principles so that command line option handling simply doesn't matter enough there. I don't have enough rep there to offer a bounty or close the question.
So I feel cross posting is appropriate here. I have however, deleted the original there to be on the safe side.

Comment: Emacs runs but displays an error if you run it with an invalid option.

Comment: Your choice of example applications seems biased. There are bajillions of simple GUI programs which simply refuse to run if you pass in an invalid option. The bigger behemoths are probably less likely to do that because there might be an extension or etc which could parse an option which you can't know until you are up and running.

Comment: There is also a question of intended audience. Tools for unsophisticated users like Word simply will seem broken if they don't run when you click and drool.

Comment: It was not a representative sample. Hence my asking the question.

Comment: I think the downvote was for cross posting before I deleted the original question on Ux. I didn't want to do that until I could link it to this one.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I am afraid some regulars on Stack Overflow will think this is not properly programming-related, or too broad. I'm kind of on the fence myself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single correct answer to this question, however I tend to agree that silent failure is not a very friendly response. I personally prefer a hybrid of devenv and word: display an error to console and/or dialog but don't exit if the error is not a fatal error. For instance, if the command line failure is that a specified file to be opened is not found, then I generally pop up a dialog with the file not found error message with 3 buttons: "Ignore" (which just ignores and opens with no file), Cancel (which closes the app to allow retry from the external environment) or "Find File" which opens up the Open file dialog, prepopulated with the command line value that failed. This allows for easy edits / searches.

The bottom line is, let your user know what the problem is and attempt to provide a convenient means to solve it. The key is trying to anticipate the user's needs and accommodate them when reasonably possible.

Answer (score 1):

Error handling is one of the big architecture foundations, and I would design a solution in terms of multiple behaviours.

**PEOPLE**

For best results, expect errors, since they will occur sometimes. The app needs a plan that works for these personas. Reliability over time and fast problem resolution are usually key concerns.

- End Users
- Technical Support Staff
- Product Owners

**ERROR TYPES**

There are multiple types of error, such as these. Design a plan for handling each of them. Rehearse all such errors so that as an engineer you are prepared for production incidents.

- Startup errors
- Server errors (status 500)
- Client errors (status 400)
- Invalid input errors

For example, I would usually follow the VS Code approach for startup errors, but I would not terminate the app for the other types of error.

**TREAT ERRORS AS DATA**

Design error models that keep users informed, assist support staff, and enable you to effectively measure occurrences over time.

Avoid extremes, such as a useless error display that says `Oops - something has gone wrong`, or displaying secure information from exceptions to users.

You can then use error data however you want, and refine the UX over time. One technique that works well for both users and support staff is an `error summary view` that can be clicked to see an `error details view`.

**FURTHER DETAILS**

Also, GUIs do not stand alone. In distributed architectures, errors they experience often originate from other components. For some thoughts on end-to-end solutions, see my blog post on [Error handling and supportability](https://authguidance.com/error-handling-and-supportability/).

Comment: While you have made some good points you have not actually answered the question I asked. To be honest your answer looks a little like chatGPT could have provided it. Apologies if that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

#### Distinguish between user and app errors

When it comes to dealing with errors in your GUI application, you've got to think about how it's going to affect the user. First off, figure out if the error is something the user goofed up on, like typing in the wrong file path, or if it's a real issue with the app itself, like it's missing some crucial pieces.

#### User Errors: Keep it User-Friendly

For user errors, you don't want to annoy people by slamming the app shut every time they make a little mistake. If they mess up a file path, just let them know with a clear error message. Closing the app for that kind of stuff is unnecessary.

#### App Issues: Be Strict

If the error is critical and results in more errors down the line, shut it down and give a short error message that quickly sums up the error and a detailed error message (maybe put the detailed error behind a "read more" button so non-expert users aren't overwhelmed). Log those errors so you or maybe the user can figure out what went wrong behind the scenes and try to fix it. For example a missing dependency is easy to fix but is also crucial for the program.

#### Test your app

Testing is crucial. Make sure your error strategy works for your app and doesn't drive users crazy. And don't forget —simple, user-friendly error messages can make a world of a difference in how folks perceive your app.

#### Conclusion

In the end, go with what fits your app best. You already looked at how other successful apps handle errors, but tweak it to match your style and what your app needs.

Answer (score -1):

I'd let it run and notify user silently in cli but giving AN OPTION inside program to display errors at startup isn't generally a bad idea...
(Unless app isn't made specially for developers ofcourse, then you can make error popups at default)